# Despite filter "type=cm:content", Alfresco audit writes about folders too

Tags: alfresco, audit

I want Alfresco to audit document changes but not folder changes. For instance, if a folder containing a document is deleted, only the document deletion should show up in audit.

In Alfresco 5.1.0 I defined a single audit application `myapp` with this configuration:

```
audit.tagging.enabled=false
audit.myapp.enabled=true
audit.myapp.sub-actions.enabled=false
audit.filter.myapp.default.enabled=true
audit.filter.myapp.transaction.type=cm:content
audit.filter.myapp.transaction.path=/app:company_home/app:shared/.*
audit.filter.myapp.transaction.action=CREATE|READ|UPDATE CONTENT|CHECK IN|DELETE|COPY|MOVE|DOWNLOAD|addNodeAspect|deleteNodeAspect
```

If my understanding is correct, `type=cm:content` limits audit events to only those about Alfresco **documents**? If I wanted events about folders too I would write `cm:folder;cm:content` there.

Despite this code, when querying `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/audit/query/myapp` I still get audit events whenever a **folder** is created or deleted.
What am I doing wrong?

Audit after folder creation:

```
  {
     "id":945,
     "application":"myapp",
     "user":"user1",
     "time":"2017-03-16T13:20:59.480+09:00",
     "values":
     {
                 "\/bmyapp\/transaction\/action":"CREATE"
                 ,"\/myapp\/transaction\/path":"\/app:company_home\/app:shared\/cm:folder1"
     }
  },
```

Audit after folder deletion:

```
  {
     "id":947,
     "application":"myapp",
     "user":"user1",
     "time":"2017-03-16T13:24:51.098+09:00",
     "values":
     {
                 "\/myapp\/transaction\/action":"DELETE"
                 ,"\/myapp\/transaction\/path":"\/app:company_home\/app:shared\/cm:folder1"
     } 
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add a `RecordValue key="type"` element in my audit application's XML definition file, as seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Audit xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2 alfresco-audit-3.2.xsd">
    ...
    <Application name="myapp" key="myapp">
        <AuditPath key="transaction">
            <RecordValue key="type" dataExtractor="simpleValue" dataSource="/myapp/transaction/type" dataTrigger="/myapp/transaction/type" />
            ...
        </AuditPath>
        ...
    </Application>
</Audit>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to filter audit data like that, then you are getting audit filtering wrong !
There is actually no out of the box way for filtering audit data on a per application basis, and you can only do that on a per producer basis! I know there might be some confusion from the alfresco docs as the out of the box audit application name (alfresco-access) just happens to be the same as the name of the data producer (alfresco-access).

What you can do actually is to use alfresco-access (the data provider) in your filtering setup, and your filtering will work:

```
audit.filter.alfresco-access.transaction.type=cm:content;~.*
```

**Please note:** That will, however, filter out all audit events coming out of the data producer (for all audit applications)

I have once implemented an extension to the audit component, making it possible to filter out entries on the audit application level, based on the DataExtractor used along with a path rewriting naming convention, so if that what you want achieve, then its probably better to do it that way; or alternatively write your own dataproducer to generate the data you need, and have one audit application consume that filtered data !